# Manipulating iterations of for loop JS

Tags: node.js, for-loop

I have a for loop that has a nested loop, that runs a function, and on each iteration that function generates a random number from 0-10 inclusive. 
is there a way to manipulate the iterations of nested loop, to make it run the second iteration the same function with another arguments. For instance I need my loop to run the first iteration, check if the 10-random number is non zero, and on second iteration run the function from 0 to the remnant of 10-same random number

```
function bowl(){
    var p1,
        p2,
        scr1=new Array,
        scr2=new Array,
        fin=[];

    function roll1(min,max){
        p1=Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
        scr1.push(p1)
        fin.push(scr1)
    }
    function roll2(min,max){
        p2=Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
        scr2.push(p2)
        fin.push(scr1)
    }
    function left1(){
        return 10-p1
    }
    function left2(){
        return 10-p2
    }
    for(var j=1;j<11;j++){
         console.log("roll " + j)
         for(var i=1;i<4;i++){
             roll1(0,10)
         }
    }
    console.log(fin)
}
```

Comment: what does `10-random` number mean? Is that mean 10th random number?

Comment: @wrangler means 10 minus the random number